# Couchdb sum error on all map views

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

My cloudant database was working fine and then I started receiving a `SUMERROR` on all my map views. There is no reduce functions on most of the map functions.

```
{error: "invalid_value",…}
error: "invalid_value"
reason: "The _sum function requires that map values be numbers, arrays of numbers, or objects, not 'null'. Objects cannot be mixed with other data structures. Objects can be arbitrarily nested, provided that the values for all fields are themselves numbers, arrays of numbers, or objects."
ref: 2090670111
```

I am not sure what the cause of the error is and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map function emits a value for one of the documents which is not one of the types listed in the error message, you might have a document which as an unexpected value for the field you are emitting in the map function.